# Browser Compatibility/Support for newer Versions

Tags: javascript, browser

I would like to support newer browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Opera etc. for my application. My application currently works well with IE8.

How can I add support for newer versions? Is there any javascript bundle that is readily available and we can use by including tags like

```
&lt;!--[if !IE]&gt;&lt;!--&gt;
&lt;script src="--JS Bundle for newer versions" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

&lt;!--[if gt IE 8]&gt;
    &lt;script src="--JS Bundle for newer versions" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;![endif]--&gt;&lt;!--&lt;![endif]--&gt;
```

And also let me know if there is any tools to test Browser compatibility

Comment: What specifically *isn't* working? Newer browsers are typically backwards compatible with older code, unless that old code has some significant problems. You don't need to explicitly "support" newer browsers.

Comment: It's a bit peculiar to "add support for newer versions" -- usually it's the other way around. Anyway, the best tools to test browser compatibility are the browsers themselves. Install them and try the app.

Comment: It's also uncommon to have two different scripts for different browser versions. Usually you'd just make sure every script you have work as intended in all versions you want to support.

Comment: There are various tools available in market and you can google it to test cross browser compatibility but I suggest [crossbrowsertesting](http://crossbrowsertesting.com).

Comment: I'm having certain methods like createPopup(),showModalDialog() which are supported in before version of IE8,which is not supported in chrome/firefox.               I'm also having frames  in the html pages where i access certain fields by  document.frames[frm1].location.href which are not working in chrome.Could anyone have better idea of solving this??

Answer (score 0):

Newer web browsers are backwards compatible. You should not need to take any action to run your application in a newer version of a browser.

Comment: Can I get an official document of this?

Comment: I don't know of any official document on this. It is more a general rule of thumb. Browser makers don't want to break peoples existing pages when they release a new version. However from time to time certain features are deprecated. I am afraid you just have to know what features you are using and test everywhere.